# php break not working as intended?

Tags: php, loops, break

I have a for loop that loops through xml. I then fetch results from the database and look for the id.

What happens is that when an id is found and the break happens, it stops both the while loop and the parent for loop. I just want to stop the while loop. How do I get this to work as intended?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file/path/here');

$articles = $xml->article;
$total_articles = count($articles);

// Cycle through the list of articles
for($a=0; $a<$total_articles; $a++)
{
    // Check if article already exists
    // MySQLi select statement goes here

    $exists = false;
    while($a = $article_result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if($a['article_id'] == $id)
        {
            $exists = true;
            break 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alive That would simply do nothing really in this case.

Comment: `// MySQLi select statement goes here` - it shouldn’t; select queries inside loops are at thing you want to avoid if possible, that usually has bad performance.

Comment: `break 1` should break only the `while` loop (in fact you can omit the `1`). Which means this code sample is insufficient to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I've tried that but the process goes into an infinite loop which I have to get my hosting company to kill.

Comment: maybe $a<$total_articles  is already consumed fully.

Comment: you are over-writing `$a` varible inside `while()` . take another variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're setting `$a` to `$article_result->fetch_assoc()`.

Here:

```
...
while($a = $article_result->fetch_assoc())
...
```

`[] < 1` returns false for me, at least for php7.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realise I was using $a in both loops. Problem solved.